# Why is scipy.interpolate.griddata so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate between ~400,000 data points that are **not** on a regular grid. However I can't seem to ever get it to finish running! I'm trying to interpolate the values of the function at points on a grid that is 200x200 (~40,000) data points. Here are the function calls I'm issuing:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

#Load in all the data
[raw_x_val,raw_y_val,raw_z_val] = load_data('filename')

#Generate interpolating mesh
[x_interp,y_interp] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min_interp_val,max_interp_val,200),np.linspace(min_interp_val,max_interp_val,200))
z_interp = griddata((raw_x_val,raw_y_val),raw_z_val,(x_interp,y_interp),method='linear')
```

I've looked at the data output from `load_data`, and it seems like everything loads fine. The dimensions of `raw_x_val`,`raw_y_val` and `raw_z_val` are `(410500,)`. I let it run for about half an hour and it never really finishes!
Alternatively, I tried to run a very similar set of function calls in `MATLAB` and I was able to get everything loaded and interpolated in about 2 seconds!

Am I doing something wrong in python, or is it just that the `scipy.interpolate.griddata` function is not meant to handle this kind of data. Alternately would any of have suggestions about what functions/libraries I could use to do this. I'd ideally not want to do this inside of `MATLAB`

Comment: I suggest removing the tag [tag:MATLAB] from the question, since you do not want an answer in that language. I can tell you though that MATLAB can easily process 400k data points in `griddata`

Comment: thanks, I've fixed it! MATLAB, seems to have no problems processing the data, I'm trying to do the analysis on my data with open-source code so that I can distribute the program to other people.

Comment: That's strange, the documentation for scipy v0.14 says that `griddata()` takes 3 positional arguments, yet you have only two. What version are you using?

Comment: Is that the actual code? Your function call to `griddata` does not make sense: I guess `raw_z_val` is a function of `raw_x_val` and `raw_y_val` and in that case you should list it as the second positional parameter. If not, please have a look at the definition of [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) and make sure you match the input parameters.

Comment: If you have access to the MATLAB compiler you can compile to C/C++ and distribute your code in those languages. I advise you though to try and get python working, since it is much better to write directly in a language, instead of machine-translating code.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo in the question. I've just fixed it. In case it matters I'm using scipy 0.16

Comment: Your call to `np.meshgrid` also makes no sense - if you want to generate two output arrays then you will need to pass in two vectors.

Comment: Now that that's cleared up, would it be possible to add a link to your dataset? As well as specify what `min_interp_val` and `max_interp_val` are for you, so others can reproduce the problem. As it looks more decent now, my guess is that your scipy installation isn't in order. Perhaps consider reinstalling scipy?

Comment: I tested a modified example from `griddata()` docs, with 410500 points interpolated to a 200x200 grid — see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fjarri/b6f1faefa95995d119b8). The `griddata()` call takes 4 seconds on my machine. Could you try to run it and say how long it takes for you?

Comment: In python, you do not need the `[`  and `]` for unpacking function return values.

Comment: If you are running an old version of Scipy (`scipy.__version__` earlier than 0.12.0 or so), consider upgrading.