# Why scipy.griddata is much slower than matlab's griddata?

Tags: matlab, scipy

I could find some existing topics about this but somehow I could not find an answer...

Here is a python example taken from https://gist.github.com/fjarri/b6f1faefa95995d119b8 (already used in [Why is scipy.interpolate.griddata so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882691/why-is-scipy-interpolate-griddata-so-slow)), giving

Python:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2
 
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:200j, 0:1:200j]

points = np.random.rand(410500, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

t1 = time.time()
grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
print(time.time() - t1)
```

the print gives always about 6.4secs

Matlab :

```
[grid_x, grid_y] = meshgrid(1:200, 1:200);
points = rand(410500, 2);
x=points(:,1);
y=points(:,2);
values = x.*(1-x).*cos(4*pi*x).*sin(4*pi*y.^2).^2;
tic;vq = griddata(x,y,values,grid_x,grid_y,'linear');toc;
```

the print gives always about 2.4secs.

Someone knows why is there such a big difference between the two software ? And if there is a solution to accelerate scipy.griddata ? I deal with many large arrays of scattered points and griddata is responsible for most of my computation time... but I need to use python for this and it is very slow.

Comment: Because MATLAB is a corporation that specialized in writing high perfomance code that sells for quite a sum of money. If they could not be better (and keep the secret how) no one would buy MATLAB. This is the answer always to "why is MATLAB faster than XX". Because its a product and they work hard to make it so.

Comment: I love Matlab and I disregard people who think that it's evil and that python is much better. Matlab's simplicity just beats python and that's enough for me who's not an expert. However, I've never encountered such a big difference in time computation for other functions, and by experience when there is such a big difference, it is usually that the user does not use the function as it should in the given context, or someone has found a way to improve the available function.

Comment: I have done quite a lot of MATLAB and python code duplication. My experience is that almost always MATLAB is faster, or MUCH faster than python, for native operations, such as convolutions, matrix operations etc. Most of the times, I suspected (due to process monitoring) that it comes from the highly efficient multithreading that MATLAB has, but its hard to make any further assesment.

Comment: Interesting. My experience has been "faster" but never "much faster" and not a factor or 3 times faster.

Comment: Code looping over individual values in an array is easily 100x as fast in MATLAB. Nevertheless, I would suspect that MATLAB uses a different algorithm altogether for `griddata`. There are lots of choices to be made when interpolating non-uniformly sampled data.